# copy folders from one team project to another

Tags: team-foundation-server, copy

i have one TFS server, with 4 team projects in it. i want to copy folders of of one team project into another team project.
here's the tree -

```
TFS(Server)
 |___ A1(Team project1)
 |___ A2(Team project2)
         |______________(Folder1)
         |______________(Folder2)
         |______________(Folder3)
         |______________(Folder4)
 |___ A3(Team project3)
 |___ A4(Team project4)
```

I want to copy folders in A2(TeamProject2)-->(Folder2) only to A1(Team Project1)
How do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think source control explorer has a copy option on the right click menu.  This question might get a better response on StackOverflow though.